# execute function after function is not working swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, ios10

This is the function which i want to get execute after downloading all details and another function whcih is to update UIElements to after downloading. This function is inside "CurrentWeather.swift"

```
func downloadWeatherDetails(completed: ( () -> () )){
    // tell Alimofire where to download
    let currentWeatherURL = URL(string: CURRENT_WEATHER_URL)!
    Alamofire.request(currentWeatherURL).responseJSON{ response in

        let result = response.result
        if let dict  = result.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>{

            if let name = dict["name"] as? String{
                self._cityName = name.capitalized
                print(self._cityName)
            }

            if let weather = dict["weather"] as? [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>]{
                if let main = weather[0]["main"] as? String{
                    self._weatherType = main.capitalized
                    print(self._weatherType)
                }
            }

            if let main = dict["main"] as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>{
                if let currentTemperature = main["temp"] as? Double {
                    let kelvinToFarenhitePreDevision = (currentTemperature * (9/5) - 459.67 )
                    let kelvinToFarenhite = Double(round(10 * kelvinToFarenhitePreDevision/10))
                    self._currentTemp = kelvinToFarenhite
                    print(self._currentTemp)
                }
            }


        }


    }
    completed()
}
```

}

and this function is to update UIEmelents

```
    func updateMainUI(){

    dateLabel.text = currentWeather.date
    currentTempLabel.text = "\(currentWeather.currentTemp)"
    currentWeatherTypeLabel.text = currentWeather.weatherType
    locationLabel.text = currentWeather.cityName
    currentWeatherImage.image = UIImage(named: currentWeather.weatherType)
}
```

and this is to call them on Override func viewDidLoad()

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self

    currentWeather.downloadWeatherDetails { () -> () in 
        self.updateMainUI()
    }
}
```

now when i am executing this its not updating UI data
but its printing them inside console

can anybody help me with this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `completed()` before your request is completed.

```
        completed() //<- you need to call the completion handler inside the closure.
    }
    //completed() //<- this would be called before completion
}
```

I haven't checked other parts of your code, but at least you need to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Your weatherDetails are getting downloaded asynchronously. Inside viewDidLoad(), self.updateMainUI() is getting called before your response is received and parsed. So just put the UIUpdateMainUI() method inside and at the end of this block :

```
if let dict  = result.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>{
}
```

If you are requesting from a different class, then design a protocol there. Conform it in the viewController you want to update. From the if-let block above, at the end of parsing, call the delegate method of the viewController to be update. And of course, inside the delegate method, update your UI. 
Thanks.